# Существует ли псевдокласс на проверку пустоты input?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Возникла проблема при анимации label нужно сместить ее при фокусе. Это сделал как `input:focus + label {стили}` Но только как убираю фокус с инпута, label возвращается на место и перекрывает текст. Как сделать так чтобы когда input не пустой задать label стили.

Это при фокусе на инпут.

[image: при фокусе]

Убираю фокус

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код добавьте вместо картинок

Comment: Есть псевдо селектор `:blank`. Добавьте его инпуту.

Comment: @dresser [действительно, почему бы и нет](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ablank)

Comment: @InDevX, он с заделом на будущее ))

Comment: Приложите разметку и стили.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
input:focus + label, 
input:valid + label 
 {
   ...
 }
```

На инпуты required добавьте

Comment: Спасибо, работает